# What are best practices: ajax content - jsRender - make it SEO friendly

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, jsrender

I am making an app that displays different lists on the home page...

for better performance I pre-cache json with php and put it into a file and the using ajax call I parse the items using a template with jsRender from Boris Moore. Works really fast and it is perfect.

But how to serve the same content to search engines?
The problem is not in escaped fragment ... the problem is keeping it simple, without overhead...

Ideally there would be a jsRender php port that would parse the template into  html so I can then cache it and serve it on the fly to SE.

But I couldn't find any, specially 'couse jsRender is still under development and it is changing.

so is there a way to fetch js generated content?

I know I could open a page in browser let jsRender do the job and then save $('#list').html() content with ajax.... but I have hundreds of different pages that need to pe cached couple of times a day, so that option is not really viable...

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Serving SE
  specific content to the SE is a great way to get banned from SE (if
  we are talking about Google), see their terms
- If you want google to index the content of the dynamically rendered stuff than you might run into challenges, but according to the web, Google does index AJAX read more at http://searchengineland.com/its-official-googles-proposal-for-crawling-ajax-urls-is-live-37298
- If you want google to crawl based on info revealed by the dynamic content then you need a sitemap.xml, that could be generated in the same run as the cache json. The sitemap.xml is the only valid way to "hint" google (rather then deceiving it)

UPDATE in reflection of the comment:
If JsRender is the core value that you want to keep then you might just use NodeJS to execute those jsRender files and then have the output included in the PHP file or whatever way you want to service them. I checked and there are ppl how used NodeJS with jsRender: https://github.com/shtylman/node-jsrender

HTH